# I want to translate the Bible to a yet untranslated language. What legal aspects should I look for?

Tags: publishing, translation

Yes, there exists a language in which the Bible has not yet been translated to. I wish to do that translation.

Which version of the Bible can I use, and am I liable for lawsuits?

Thanks

Comment: Read https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16377/what-major-translations-of-the-bible-are-in-the-public-domain

Comment: Do you want to translate the original texts, or do you want to take an English translation and then translate that to the other language?

Comment: Keep in mind it also is important to know which sect of Christianity you are translating for.  A Catholic Bible will include 7 books not in a Protestant Bible (I do not know why this was done.).  This is more an interesting fact to know and not anything legally incorrect.  You'd be hard pressed to find someone who would actually know this and care to raise an issue.   What language are you translating it into?

Answer (score 4):

Translating any text produces a derivative work. If the original text is protected by copyright, this requites the permission of the copyright holder.

Any ancient text or translation of the Bible is totally free of copyright protection. Any version published in the US before 1926 is now out of copyright in the US. The rule3s for copyright of a Bible version are not usually different from those form any other text in a given country.

There are a few special exceptions. For example, as described on [this site](https://www.cambridge.org/about-us/who-we-are/queens-printers-patent) the King James Version (KJV) is under Crown Copyright in the UK. There could be similar special copyright rules in other countries for particular versions.

Note that the KJV is listed as PD on the list linked in the answer by user6726. But this would not be correct in the UK, although it would be in the US.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://support.biblegateway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001403507-What-Bibles-on-Bible-Gateway-are-in-the-public-domain-) purports to be a list of public domain Bibles in English, and the entries are detailed enough to make the claim credible. If you use a copyright-protected version, you have to have the permission of the copyright owner or run the risk of an infringement lawsuit, as in [this case](https://rushtopress.org/press-releases/pr041316.html) of a website with 50 translations that was shut down.

Comment: QActually, the linked listsays that it is a list of PD bible versions to be found on the Bible Gateway site. It does not say that no version not on the site is not PD.